# JavaScript: window.innerWidth wrong on certain websites

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, window, dimension

I have developed a Chrome extension that uses the browser window dimensions in certain code executions. It works well on all sites except https://epicmafia.com/home. I wonder whether there are other sites with similar problems too.

Only when I have the above site in focus, javascript returns a wrong value for window.innerWidth and even for document.documentElement.clientWidth. Since my code works on other sites, I know it does not have to do with my code, but here's how you can reproduce this problem.

Visit the above link. Open the Developer Console by pressing F12. Add any of the following to the Watch.

```
window.innerWidth

document.documentElement.clientWidth
```

If you open another website and refresh the watch, then it shows the right value.

EDIT:
My question is not remotely similar to the suggested duplicate. Please read the question properly and follow the steps to reproduce the problem, before simply reporting. This question deals with the value being wrong on certain websites and the other deals with different values across all websites.
If you tried reproducing the problem here, as mentioned, you'd notice that the return value is greater than the screen resolution, which should be impossible.

Comment: Are you reading the value when the page is fully loaded?

Comment: Yep, that's what I saw on another thread, but I am doing so when loaded. You can test yourself too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [window.innerWidth vs document.documentElement.clientWidth](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6942785/window-innerwidth-vs-document-documentelement-clientwidth)

Comment: What's your expected value and what's the actual value?

Comment: Did you even read the question or follow the steps to reproduce the error before reporting duplicate?