# $(window).width(); not work at correct position

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, function, width

Thats my code:

```
$(window).on("load scroll resize", function() 
{
    if( $( window ).width() >= 767)
    { 
        $( ".boxlogo" ).css("display","block");
        $( ".nav > li").css("margin-top","95px");`

        var s = $(window).scrollTop();
        if(s  > 1)
        {
            $( ".boxlogo" ).css("width","140px");
            $( ".navbar-color" ).css("background-color","#fff");
            $( ".dropdown-menu > li > a") .css("color","#000");
            $( ".dropdown > a ").css("color","#000");
            $( ".nav > li > a").css("color","#000");                    
            $( ".dropdown-menu > li > a") .css("text-shadow","2px 2px #fff");
            $( ".dropdown > a ").css("text-shadow","1px 1px #fff");
            $( ".nav > li > a").css("text-shadow","1px 1px #fff");
            $( ".nav > li").css("margin-top","62px");
            $( ".dropdown-menu").css("background-color","#fff");
        }
        else 
        {
            $( ".boxlogo" ).css("width","200px");
            $( ".navbar-color" ).css("background-color","transparent");                
            $( ".dropdown-menu > li > a") .css("color","#fff");
            $( ".dropdown > a ").css("color","#fff");
            $( ".nav > li > a").css("color","#fff");
            $( ".dropdown-menu > li > a") .css("text-shadow","1px 1px #000");
            $( ".dropdown > a ").css("text-shadow","1px 1px #000");
            $( ".nav > li > a").css("text-shadow","1px 1px #000");
            $( ".dropdown-menu").css("background-color","transparent");
            $( ".nav > li").css("margin-top","96px");
        }
    }//if windows
    else {
        $( ".boxlogo" ).css("display","none");
        $( ".nav > li").css("margin-top","5px");
    }
});//scroll resize*/`
```

The problem is that:

```
$( ".boxlogo" ).css("display","block");
$( ".nav > li").css("margin-top","95px");
```

not work when the windows width is 767px but at 784px...why?? thats more important because is the point when menu change style.
I have try to use if( $( window ).innerWidth() >= 767) but the problem persist.
I also try to do that with css @media but not work at all.
I'm using bootstrap.

Comment: Try first adding a printout of the relevant properties you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `$(window).width()` or something similar you could try the property `document.documentElement.clientWidth` which returns the document width (without scrollbar). At least this works for me in a similar case and across browsers as far as I can say.

Comment: Read [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7205786/1891677) for a good explanation on what `document.clientWidth` returns and when.

Comment: Besides, they are trying to match a media query in their CSS. Your code will only work as OP expects on pages without scrollbar and will misbehave when a scrollbar is present, if the current browser renders the page in desktop mode (with solid sidebars).

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu `document.clientWidth` returns undefined because it doesn't exsist. I talked about `document.documentElement.clientWidth`. Anyway, I did not say this is the most perfect solution for everyone, but it's worth a try. In my usecase it works absolutely perfect in IE11, EDGE, FF, Chrome and Brave ... with or without visible scrollbars. So I don't see a reason not to try it.

Comment: I meant `document.documentElement.clientWidth`. If you read the answer (and the question) I linked to, you would know we are referring to the same property, but it's a very good observation. In JavaScript one should be exact. But apart from that, please note you are the only one here who knows and refers to your use-case. Everyone else refers to the OP use-case, because that's what this question is about.