# Load images only for devices with > 640px screen

Tags: javascript, css

I have image that should be seen on desktop screens, but not on mobile.
I know that CSS media queries are designed only for displaying purposes, which means that on mobile device, image will still be loaded but just not displayed.
Is there a way to prevent image from loading on devices with <640px resolution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the width of the page on load, and based on that set the `src` attributes on the images if required.

```js
if(window.innerWidth > 600) {
  document.getElementById("img1").src = "//placehold.it/150";
} else {
  alert("No image loaded");
}
```

```html
<img id="img1" src="" />
```

Now, a concern might be that this merges the UI logic (i.e. the URL of the image) into JS. You can avoid that by using a data attribute such as `data-src` to keep the actual image `src` and set it dynamically to `src` based on `window.innerWidth`. Something like the following:

```js
if(window.innerWidth > 600) {
  var img = document.getElementById("img1");
  img.src = img.attributes["data-src"].value;
} else {
  alert("No image loaded");
}
```

```html
<img id="img1" src="" data-src="//placehold.it/150" />
```

Comment: That means the image is not being selected property. Check if its ID matches in the DOM through the developer tools in browser.

Comment: Thanks, it helped!
I just forgot to add "window.onload" so var img couldn't get an actual image, because it was not loaded yet

Comment: I've faced one more problem. So now when I access website from device <600 it works fine. But when I resize the window the images are not loading. Do you know if there is a way for do this?

Comment: @Dmitriy You need to use the [`resize`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/resize) handler for that.

Answer (score 2):

```
window.onload = function(){
    if(document.body.clientWidth> 600){
        // . . . code . . . 
    }
}
```

Comment: do you know what will be more accurate document.body.clientWidth or window.innerWidth?

Comment: @Dmitriy ClientWidth excludes the scrollbar width. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7205786/5894241).

Answer (score 1):

With pure CSS, you can't.

You have two options:

**Option 1: HTML5**

If you don't need to support old browsers, you can use HTML5 new tag `<picture>`. Like so:

```
<picture>
    <source 
        media="(min-width: 641px)"
        srcset="images/my_desktop_image.png">
    <source 
        media="(min-width: 451px)"
        srcset="images/my_mobile_image.png">
    <img 
        src="images/my_default_image.png" 
        alt="picture text">
</picture>
```

**Option 2: Javascript** (might be easier with jQuery library)

With jQuery, you can detect window size, and based on that load the desired image:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if($(this).width > 640) {
        // load image..
    }
});
```