# How to get position in vh and vw instead of in pixel?

Tags: javascript

so i'm doing some testing to see the position of en of an object in a frame by using this code

```
function showCoords(event) {
    var x = event.clientX;
    var y = event.clientY;
    var coords = "X coords: " + x + ", Y coords: " + y;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = coords;
}
```

But it show the position in pixels from top and left, is there a way to show it in different format like vw from left and vh from top instead of in pixels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`window.innerHeight` and `window.innerWidth` are the size of your browser window. You should be able to divide `x / window.innerWidth` and `y / window.innerHeight` to get the fractional size of the viewport.

Alternately, you could use clientWidth: [window.innerWidth vs document.documentElement.clientWidth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6942785/window-innerwidth-vs-document-documentelement-clientwidth/7205786)

Comment: Great, I'm glad! :)